# function composition in ramda.js

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

Given the following:

```
var xs = [{a: 1}, {a: 2}, {a: 3}];
R.findIndex(R.propEq('a', 2))(xs); //=> 1
R.findIndex(R.propEq('a', 4))(xs); //=> -1
```

How do I create a new function that does not bind `propEq` immediately.
I thought `curry` might do it.

```
var myfn = R.findIndex(R.propEq);
myfn('a', '2')(xs); // => 1
```

I tried curry, but I don't have it quite correct.

```
var myfn = R.findIndex(R.curry(R.propEq)); // functional programming is rusty - this is not currect
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, my first thought is that simply being explicit would be best here:

```
const findByProp = curry((key, val, xs) => findIndex(propEq(key, val), xs));

const xs = [{a: 1, b: 10}, {a: 2, b: 20}, {a: 3, b: 30}];

findByProp('a', 1, xs);  //=> 0
findByProp('a', 2)(xs);  //=> 1
findByProp('b')(30)(xs); //=> 2
```

There might be some way to make this points-free using [`useWith`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#useWith) or [`converge`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#converge) or Sanctuary's [`S` combinator](http://sanctuary.js.org/#S), but they would probably in the end not be as readable as this.

You can see this in action on the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.21.0#?code=const%20findByProp%20%3D%20curry%28%28key%2C%20val%2C%20xs%29%20%3D%3E%20findIndex%28propEq%28key%2C%20val%29%2C%20xs%29%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20xs%20%3D%20%5B%7Ba%3A%201%2C%20b%3A%2010%7D%2C%20%7Ba%3A%202%2C%20b%3A%2020%7D%2C%20%7Ba%3A%203%2C%20b%3A%2030%7D%5D%3B%0A%0AfindByProp%28%27a%27%2C%201%2C%20xs%29%3B%20%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%200%0AfindByProp%28%27a%27%2C%202%29%28xs%29%3B%20%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%201%0AfindByProp%28%27b%27%29%2830%29%28xs%29%3B%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%202)**.